# Error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysqli

When using the below command

```
$query=$comm->prepare("DELETE FROM ? WHERE id = ?");
```

I am receiving the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '? WHERE id = ?' at line 1

if i remove ? and replace it with table name the code is working properly. Please Help

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work... Nothing wrong with it..

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: For some reason its not working. Removing ? helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is used for parameters, which can change. Why are you using `?` for the table name? It remains constant.

Comment: I am passing two parameters using GET and forming the tablename. Since it is done using GET i am trying to parametrize it.

Comment: sorry mate thats not possible

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. I better change the entire table structure then.

Answer (score 2):

Table names cannot be parametrized. Since you supply the table name, and not the user (*right?*), it should be safe to concatenate/interpolate normally.

Comment: here i am trying to concatenate two GET parameters and form the table name. Since the table name is formed using GET isn't it advisable to parametrize it?

Comment: @user1885115 You should be avoiding using user input to form table names. If you have table names that can be generated, you may want to rethink your database structure. If you *absolutely must* use the user input, it should be checked against a whitelist.

Comment: thanks. I shall change the entire structure rather than whitelist